# Is there an opensource crypto-currency exchanges engine?

Tags: exchanges, alternatives, open-source, exchange-fees, intersango

I'm looking for an opensource crypto-currency exchange engine.

My preference would be for something easy to use like joomla or drupal. My exchange setup needs support for alt-coins and bitcoin.

I have discovered [intersango](https://github.com/dooglus/intersango) myself. However, sql file is corrupted, there is no creation of tables and import does not work. Plus it is bitcoin exchange only (and I need alt-coin support). Site of this exchange with "invites only", registration is closed.

Is there something super-simple that I can use to get started?

Answer (score 4):

Yeah it's called [buttercoin](http://buttercoin.com/#/) here is their [code](https://github.com/buttercoin/buttercoin).

Comment: Do you know anything else, in old school style? I'm really troubled with node.js, it want so many dependencies, and wantn't simply start. I'm currently stuck with "npm ERR! Test failed. ". I'm lurking around with google, but it is really ugly. Anything simpler, ruby/django/php based?

Comment: not that I know of sorry. Trouble with npm how? install node from [here](http://nodejs.org/) and then when you download a project with a `package.json` file just do `npm install` and all the dependencies will be downloaded.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 13.10, npm install goes well, but test fail. Looks like buttercoin under huge development stage, there are thousands of tickets, sometimes meets speech like "Installation on the Ubuntu is broken again." I currently dance with virtualbox's sister -  `vagrant up`, but it too want to download something huge, and connection breaks everytime. I'm tired.

Answer (score 4):

Peatio is an open source crypto exchange. Their README says:

> Peatio is a free and open-source crypto currency exchange implementation with the Rails framework and other cutting-edge technology.
>
> #### **Mission**
>
> Our mission is to build the world best open-source crypto currency exchange with a high performance trading engine and safety which can be trusted and enjoyed by users. Additionally we want to move the crypto currency exchange technology forward by providing support and add new features. We are helping people to build easy their own exchange around the world.

Their github page:

- https://github.com/peatio/peatio

Comment: [It can no longer be installed](https://github.com/peatio/peatio/issues/677). -1 because answer is useless and time consuming. The software no longer receive updates, so the rror won’t be corrected.

Comment: The RubyKube community apparently picked up support of the Peatio code base and built a bunch on top of it. Seems still in active development https://github.com/rubykube

Answer (score 4):

Bitsquare.io is currently the state of the art and it is open source:
https://github.com/bitsquare/bitsquare/

Comment: Yes, but adding an altcoin is ont as simple as tuning a ballet and modifying a .conf file.

Comment: Actually, adding a trading symbol is not difficult, maybe a couple of hours if you know Java and understand the blockchain.  Getting the PR commit just right, so that the team accepts it is another story...

Answer (score 1):

We've just made our exchange, MarginCall, open source. Check it out. We are going with a new project where everyone can run it's exchange and interconnect them into global ECN system.

It's written in Elixir and PHP, and also includes an API and clients for that API.

[Source code.](https://bitbucket.org/margincallio/)

https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/33y97d/our_contribution_to_bitcoin_community/

Comment: [How to not be a spammer](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

Comment: I've read your thread on reddit yesterday,  so I am aware that your answer here is useful, however you seem to be picking up spam votes due to the way it is presented. It would be great if you could add some more info such as a direct link to the source code and the name of your project to improve your answer.

Comment: @user25253 : yes, there are no install instructions. It also looks like to require Windows® because of C#.

Comment: The code base was last updated 2016-07-02

Answer (score 0):

There are few options available Like rubykube and bitHolla https://rubykube.io/
Hollaex is the exchange by bitHolla
https://coinfunda.com/best-open-source-cryptocurrency-exchange/

Answer (score 0):

You can try OpenDAX
https://www.openware.com/product/opendax
It's an open-source cryptocurrency exchange with quite a lot of features, and very actively developed

Answer (score 0):

https://www.merkeleon.com/cryptocurrency-exchange-software/

Merkeleon provides a turnkey solution for starting own Crypto Exchange for professional traders or beginners. We provide a wide listing of crypto or fiat currencies, and the support of all required order trading types such as limit, stop-limit, market, stop-market, trailing stop, trailing stop limit, Trading API.

Comment: From what I can tell by your use of "we" it sounds like you own or work for merkeleon, am I understanding this correctly?